# Why I can't measure the output voltage in a LED light bulb?

Tags: led, multimeter

Why I can't measure the output voltage in a LED light bulb using multimeter?

See the picture below :

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something wrong.  Explain what you did and maybe someone can tell you how to do it correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "output voltage"?

Comment: I've added a picture.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: It gives me random numbers: 1, 354,...

Comment: Are we assuming the voltage at the end of those two wires is the voltafe eeding that entire LED array?

Comment: Add a photo of your multimeter showing where you have the leads plugged in and the range you have selected. Hit the [Edit] link.

Answer (score 1):

The LEDs might be driven by a 120 Hz (US) waveform, which would produce a flickering light that you can see if you wave your hand across it rapidly.  Or, it might be a high frequency square wave, which would confuse a meter but be clear on a scope.

Assuming you have your meter in a DC mode, try switching to AC and see what you get.